# Error reading a local CSV file and displaying it as React component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to read a csv file local to my system ( name and location is already known) and show it to the react front-end.

Embedding the csv in code does show it properly, however cant get it to work when the file is external to the code.

What is working:

```
import { CsvToHtmlTable } from "react-csv-to-table";
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

const sampleData = `Id,Name
36967,Jephthah Creamer
...
`;

export default class ValidationReport extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{
        maxWidth: "100%",
        overflow: "auto"
      }}>
        <CsvToHtmlTable
          data={sampleData}
          csvDelimiter=','
          tableClassName='table table-striped table-hover'
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I try to parse it using papaparse , it doesn't work:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM, { render } from "react-dom";
import { CsvToHtmlTable } from "react-csv-to-table";


/* CSV IMPORTING*/
import * as Papa from "papaparse";
import file from "./abc.csv";

import "./index.css";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.parseCsvToObj();
  }

  componentDidMount() { }

  parseCsvToObj() {
    let self = this;
    Papa.parse(file, {
      complete: function (results) {
        let dataArray = results.data;
        let newObj = {};
        dataArray.forEach(item => {
          let addobj = {
            name: item[0],
            age: item[1],
          };
          newObj = [...newObj, addobj];
        });
        self.setState({ data: newObj });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{
        maxWidth: "100%",
        overflow: "auto"
      }}>
        <CsvToHtmlTable
          data={this.state.data}
          csvDelimiter=','
          tableClassName='table table-striped table-hover'
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

It gives me:

```
TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
(anonymous function)
D:/myapp/src/App.js:37
  34 |       name: item[0],
  35 |       age: item[1],
  36 |     };
> 37 |     newObj = [...newObj, addobj];
     | ^  38 |   });
  39 |   self.setState({ data: newObj });
  40 | }
```

I would also like to display a local HTML in a similar way ( to React UI).

Any help without using jQuery will be great.

Comment: what does `dataArray` contain ?

Comment: Id,Name
36967,Jephthah Creamer

Comment: I meant, what type of data is that ? is that an `array` or `object` ?

Comment: it contains array